# jQuery toggle image not switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created expandable links where the arrow changes when you expand the link. Expandable works great and the arrow keeps changing correctly when I expand the other link. It doesn't switch correctly if I expand the same link.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yf5brc3e/).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side-expand">
  <li class="expandor">
    <a class="adobe" href="#" id="vid_link3">Adobe Digital Editions</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="link22"><i class="icon-video"></i>
        Introduction</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expandor">
    <a class="android" href="#" id="vid_link4">Android</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="link29"><i class="icon-video"></i>
        Introduction</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.expandor > a:first-child').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this).next('ul');
  $(".side-expand li ul").not($this).slideUp();
  $this.slideToggle();
  $('.side-expand > li').css('background-color', 'transparent');

  $('.side-expand > li').removeClass('dexpandor');

  var visibleUL = $('.side-expand li').find('ul').is(':visible');
  if (visibleUL) {
    $(this).parent('li').css('background-color', 'transparent', 'font-weight', 'normal').addClass('dexpandor');
  }
});
```

[arrow not changing for the same toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEZic.png)

Comment: I don't see an arrow in the demo.

Comment: @amflare, I added a image

Comment: You need to post the complete code example *in your question*, not only in a fiddle.

Comment: @j08691 you mean html too?

Comment: I mean the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) belongs in your question first. Third-party sites like jsFiddle are an optional second.

Comment: @j08691, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing lines 8 through 13 with the following should toggle your arrow class properly:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('dexpandor');
$(this).parent().toggleClass('dexpandor');
```

Comment: Even though I had the same idea, what's the purpose of your first line? I totally agree with your second line.

Comment: @Olli1511 Well, because the second statement is specific to the object on which the currently executing method has been invoked. So, without that first line, there is nothing removing the class from other list items when a subsequent click action occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class change code in `slideToggle()` callback. Because the `ul` is hidden only when slide is complete, which is when you need to remove the class.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yf5brc3e/3/)

```js
$('.expandor > a:first-child').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this).next('ul');
  $(".side-expand li ul").not($this).slideUp();
  $this.slideToggle(function() {
    $('.side-expand > li').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $('.side-expand > li').removeClass('dexpandor');
    var visibleUL = $(this).closest('li').find('ul').is(':visible');
    if (visibleUL) {
      $(this).parent('li').css('background-color', 'transparent', 'font-weight', 'normal').addClass('dexpandor');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.side-expand li ul {
  display: none;
}

.expandor {
  background-image: url("https://odhelp.blob.core.windows.net/content/artifacts/img/right-arrow-small.png");
}

.expandor,
.dexpandor {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: right 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dexpandor {
  background-image: url("https://odhelp.blob.core.windows.net/content/artifacts/img/down-arrow-small.png");
}

.side-expand li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.side-expand li a {
  background-size: 25px auto !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="side-expand">
  <li class="expandor">
    <a id="vid_link3" value="6plk07k8op" href="#" class="adobe">Adobe Digital Editions</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a value="6plk07k8op" href="#" id="link22"><i class="icon-video"></i> Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a value="q1kogk5dc2" href="#" id="link23"><i class="icon-video"></i> Install</a></li>
      <li><a value="zmdge1whxu" href="#" id="link24"><i class="icon-video"></i> Authorize your computer</a></li>
      <li><a value="snl5pnvv27" href="#" id="link25"><i class="icon-video"></i> Read eBooks</a></li>
      <li><a value="8ldljcbtw0" href="#" id="link26"><i class="icon-video"></i> Return eBooks </a></li>
      <li><a value="tfrp7xjgus" href="#" id="link27"><i class="icon-video"></i> Transfer eBooks to reader </a></li>
      <li><a value="men1mw9an3" href="#" id="link28"><i class="icon-video"></i> Remove eBooks from reader</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expandor">
    <a id="vid_link4" value="ayfssj4211" href="#" class="android">Android</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a value="ayfssj4211" href="#" id="link29"><i class="icon-video"></i> Introduction </a></li>
      <li><a value="aqv1ieh6zd" href="#" id="link30"><i class="icon-video"></i> Install the OverDrive app</a> </li>
      <li><a value="ospa26ccnh" href="#" id="link37"><i class="icon-video"></i> Return and share titles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the click event, it toggle the class :

```
  $(this).parent('li').css('background-color','transparent', 'font-weight', 'normal').toggleClass('dexpandor','expandor');
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yf5brc3e/6/)

Comment: that doesn't work right, the second arrow doesn't switch when you click the first link and it was expanded before. But no worries I have it working now. Thanks